# Ionic hotlink image from other sites

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm currently learning ionic by making a 4chan reader for mobile. The thing is, the images that i want to show from api won't show up on mobile but shows up on pc. Well, it usually doesn't show up on pc either (because of the hotlink protection 4chan has), but since i added `<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">` in index.html it shows up now on pc with a browser.

Now obviously, adding that line doesn't work when i'm running on my phone. Is there any other way to bypass this thing?

Comment: It will work on phones that do respect `no-referrer`. What browser do you have on your phone, exactly?

Comment: i have chrome, but i didn't use any browser when i'm running on my phone. i build the .apk